# In pose mode, changes revert when I move the timeline

Tags: animation, pose-mode, timeline

If I make a change, it moves back the moment I move the timeline, as seen here,
https://i.gyazo.com/3ec8b06336418e6956fccca3f5c38ba8.mp4

What causes this? (also, it happens even though keyframes are created.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer myself...turned out there was some data on the non-linear timeline that was messing it up. I deleted it and it fixed the problem.